# Insert a rectangle on every page of a Word document using VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I would like to insert a rectangle of size page Width & page Height starting at the top-left of every page of the Word document. I'm able to get the page height and width of every page using the Pages/Page interface.

I'm trying to use the following function on every page

```
Shape shape = activeDoc.Shapes.AddShape(
                        (int)Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, pgW, pgH);
```

However, I'm unable to get the output I want. The rectangles are not inserted at the top left of the page such that they cover the entire page. The document can contain header/footer.

I need one rectangle on every page filling the entire page. I would like to know, how to achieve this?

Comment: Why not simply put the rectangle in your header?

Comment: That's what I also said

Answer (score 0):

Use the shape.leftRelative with enum wdShapePositionRelative

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdshapepositionrelative?view=word-pia

Ditto topRelative

Note that I'm doing this from memory.

If you want this on every page, then why not say it in the header?